# Rails button_tag submit button not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following two `button_tags` on my rails 5.2 form:

```
<%= button_tag "Save for Later", type: 'submit', name: "application_status_id", value: 2, class: "btn btn-light" %>
<%= button_tag "Submit for Consideration", type: 'submit', name: "application_status_id", value: 3, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

They were previously working, but now when I click on them nothing happens.  No page loads, no new lines in the server, just nothing.

When I change `button_tag` to `link_to` (as recommended in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50325140/button-tag-not-working-inside-table-in-rails)) the styling on the buttons disappears, the form refreshes, nothing is saved, and this happens in the server:

```
Started GET "/app_forms/new?class=btn+btn-primary&name=application_status_id&type=submit&value=3" for ::1 at 2019-12-04 11:33:00 -0800
Processing by AppFormsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"class"=>"btn btn-primary", "name"=>"application_status_id", "type"=>"submit", "value"=>"3"}
  Value Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "values".* FROM "values" WHERE "values"."selected" = $1 ORDER BY "values"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["selected", true], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5
  Rendering app_forms/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered app_forms/_form.html.erb (43.8ms)
  Rendered app_forms/new.html.erb within layouts/application (47.9ms)
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/layouts/_navbar.html.erb:20
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (22.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_notifications.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 634ms (Views: 483.5ms | ActiveRecord: 34.6ms)
```

Any ideas on how to get this working?  The `app_form#create` method looks like this:

```
  def create
    @app_form = AppForm.new(app_form_params)
    @app_form.user_id = current_user.id
    @app_form.application_status_id = params[:application_status_id]
    @app_form.final_decision_id = 1
    @app_form.funding_status_id = 1
    if @app_form.application_status_id == 3
      @app_form.submitted = true
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @app_form.save
        if @app_form.application_status_id == 3
          Log.create(category: "User Action", action: "New Application Submitted", automatic: false, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: "AppForm", object_id: @app_form.id, taken_by_user: true, user_id: @app_form.user.id)
          if ApplicationChangeMailer.new_application_email(@app_form).deliver
            Log.create(category: "Email", action: "New Application Email Sent to Committee", automatic: true, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: "AppForm", object_id: @app_form.id, taken_by_user: false)
          end
          format.html { redirect_to user_path(current_user), notice: 'Your application has been successfully submitted.  You will receive an email when the committee reaches a decision.' }
        else
          Log.create(category: "User Action", action: "New Application Created", automatic: false, object: true, object_linkable: true, object_category: "AppForm", object_id: @app_form.id, taken_by_user: true, user_id: @app_form.user.id)
          format.html { redirect_to user_path(current_user), notice: 'Your application has been successfully saved.  It will not be reviewed until you submit it for consideration.' }
        end
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @app_form }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @app_form.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And the (very long) form looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@app_form) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="form-inputs">


    <% if @app_form.new_record? %>
      <section id="application-type-section">
        <h2 class="toca-uppercase text-center mb-3">I want to apply for a...</h2>
        <%= f.hidden_field :application_type %>
        <div class="row mb-5">

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
            <div class="select-box application-type-box" id="hardship">
              <h5 class="toca-uppercase">Hardship</h5>
              <%= image_tag "Hardship.png", class: "ball-mini pb-2", alt: "Soccer ball that needs help with a hardship." %>
            </div> <!-- select box -->
          </div> <!-- col -->

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
            <div class="select-box application-type-box" id="scholarship">
              <h5 class="toca-uppercase">Scholarship</h5>
              <%= image_tag "Scholarship.png", class: "ball-mini pb-2", alt: "Soccer ball in a graduation cap." %>
            </div> <!-- select box -->
          </div> <!-- col -->

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 text-center">
            <div class="select-box application-type-box" id="charity">
              <h5 class="toca-uppercase">Charity</h5>
              <%= image_tag "Charity.png", class: "ball-mini pb-2", alt: "Soccer ball ready to do some charity work." %>
            </div> <!-- select box -->
          </div> <!-- col -->

        </div> <!-- row -->
      </section>
    <% end %>


    <section id="my-info-section" class="z-depth-1 p-5 my-5 info-section">
      <h2 class="toca-uppercase text-center">My Information</h2>
      <p class="text-center"><small>This information is anonymous and will not be visible to the deciding committee.</small></p>
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :full_name, class: "form-control", required: true, id: "full_name" %>
            <label for="full_name">Full Name</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->

        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :date, placeholder: "Select Application Date", class: "form-control datepicker", id: "date" %>
            <label for="date">Application Date</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->

        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :start_date, placeholder: "Select Start Date", class: "form-control datepicker", id: "start_date" %>
            <label for="start_date">Date You Started at TOCA</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :position, class: "form-control", id: "position", required: true %>
            <label for="position">Position</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :branch, class: "form-control", id: "branch", required: true %>
            <label for="branch">TOCA Branch</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :email_non_toca, class: "form-control mb-4", id: "non-toca-email", required: true %>
            <label for="non-toca-email">Email (Non-TOCA)</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :mobile, class: "form-control mb-4", id: "mobile", required: true %>
            <label for="mobile">Mobile Phone</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->

        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :address, class: "form-control mb-4", id: "address", required: true %>
            <label for="address">Your Street Address</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-5 col-lg-3">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :city, class: "form-control mb-4", id: "city", required: true %>
            <label for="city">City</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-lg-1">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :state, class: "form-control mb-4", id: "state", required: true %>
            <label for="state">State</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :zip, class: "form-control mb-4", id: "zip", required: true %>
            <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->
      </div> <!-- row -->

    </section> <!-- my info section -->


    <section id="for-other-hardship" class="z-depth-1 p-5 my-5 hardship-only">
      <h2 class="toca-uppercase text-center">Information for Recipient</h2>
      <p class="text-center"><small>Fill out this section if you are applying on the behalf of another TOCA employee.</small></p>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="field form-check text-left for_other">
          <%= f.check_box :for_other, class: "form-check-input", id: "for_other" %>
          <%= f.label "This hardship is for someone OTHER THAN myself.", class: "form-check-label", for: "for_other" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="for-other-content hidden">
        <div class="row mt-4">

          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="md-form">
              <%= f.text_field :for_other_email, class: "form-control mb-4", id: "for-other-email", required: true %>
              <label for="for-other-email">Your Non-TOCA Email Address</label>
            </div> <!-- md-form -->
          </div> <!-- col -->
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="md-form">
              <%= f.text_field :recipient_toca_email, class: "form-control mb-4", id: "recipient-toca-email", required: true %>
              <label for="recipient-toca-email">Recipient's TOCA Email</label>
            </div> <!-- md-form -->
          </div> <!-- col -->

        </div> <!-- row -->
      </div> <!-- for-other-content -->

    </section> <!-- for other hardship -->


    <section id="financial-information" class="z-depth-1 p-5 my-5 info-section">
      <h2 class="toca-uppercase text-center">Financial Information</h2>

      <div class="hardship-only row">

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :bank_name, class: "form-control mb-4", id: "bank-name" %>
            <label for="bank-name">Bank Name</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :bank_phone, class: "form-control mb-4", id: "bank-phone" %>
            <label for="bank-phone">Bank Phone</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :bank_address, class: "form-control mb-4", id: "bank-address" %>
            <label for="bank-address">Bank Address</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->

      </div> <!-- hardship only row -->

      <div class="row non-hardship">

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :institution_name, class: "form-control mb-4", id: "institution-name" %>
            <label for="institution-name">Institution Name</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :institution_contact, class: "form-control mb-4", id: "institution-contact" %>
            <label for="institution-contact">Institution Contact Person</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :institution_phone, class: "form-control mb-4", id: "institution-phone" %>
            <label for="institution-phone">Institution Phone</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :institution_address, class: "form-control mb-4", id: "institution-address" %>
            <label for="institution-address">Institution Address</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->
      </div> <!-- non-hardship row -->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.number_field :requested_amount, step: 0.01, class: "form-control mb-4", placeholder: "Numbers only (no $ or punctuation)", required: true %>
            <label for="requested-amount">Amount Requested (From TOCA Cares)</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.number_field :self_fund, step: 0.01, class: "form-control mb-4", placeholder: "Numbers only (no $ or punctuation)", required: true %>
            <label for="self-fund">Amount You Can Cover (Not Including Request)</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->
        <div class="col-12 form-check text-left mb-4 loan-check">
          <%= f.check_box :loan_preferred, class: "form-check-input", id: "loan_preferred" %>
          <%= f.label "I would prefer to receive a loan than get a grant.", class: "form-check-label", for: "loan_preferred" %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 loan-stuff">
          <%= f.text_area :loan_preferred_description, class: "form-control mb-4", placeholder: "Please describe your proposed loan vs. grant allocation." %>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- row -->


    </section> <!-- financial-information -->



    <section id="request-information" class="z-depth-1 p-5 my-5 info-section">
      <h2 class="toca-uppercase text-center">Request Information</h2>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control mb-4", placeholder: "Please describe your situation." %>
        </div> <!-- col -->
      </div> <!-- non-hardship row -->

      <div class="row hardship-only">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
          <div class="field form-check text-left">
            <%= f.check_box :accident, class: "form-check-input", id: "accident" %>
            <%= f.label :accident, class: "form-check-label", for: "accident" %>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- column -->

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
          <div class="field form-check text-left">
            <%= f.check_box :catastrophe, class: "form-check-input", id: "catastrophe" %>
            <%= f.label :catastrophe, class: "form-check-label", for: "catastrophe" %>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- column -->

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
          <div class="field form-check text-left">
            <%= f.check_box :counseling, class: "form-check-input", id: "counseling" %>
            <%= f.label :counseling, class: "form-check-label", for: "counseling" %>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- column -->

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
          <div class="field form-check text-left">
            <%= f.check_box :family_emergency, class: "form-check-input", id: "family_emergency" %>
            <%= f.label "Family Emergency", class: "form-check-label", for: "family_emergency" %>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- column -->

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
          <div class="field form-check text-left">
            <%= f.check_box :health, class: "form-check-input", id: "health" %>
            <%= f.label :health, class: "form-check-label", for: "health" %>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- column -->

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
          <div class="field form-check text-left">
            <%= f.check_box :memorial, class: "form-check-input", id: "memorial" %>
            <%= f.label :memorial, class: "form-check-label", for: "memorial" %>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- column -->

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
          <div class="field form-check text-left">
            <%= f.check_box :other_hardship, class: "form-check-input", id: "other_hardship" %>
            <%= f.label :other_hardship, class: "form-check-label", for: "other_hardship" %>
          </div>
          <div class="field col-9 d-none d-sm-block">
            <%= f.text_field :other_hardship_description, class: "form-control mb-4", style: "margin-left: 40px", placeholder: "Other Description" %>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- col -->

      </div> <!-- hardship only row -->
    </section> <!-- request-information -->










    <section id="signatures" class="z-depth-1 p-5 my-5 info-section">
      <h2 class="toca-uppercase text-center">Signatures</h2>
      <h5 class="mb-0 toca-uppercase">Statement of Intent</h5>
      <small>
        I agree that all of the information provided in this application is truthful and reflects a genuine financial hardship. In no way am I attempting to take advantage of TOCA Cares, nor my fellow employees, as this is a community fund. If it appears that I have, serious actions will be taken, jeopardizing my job at TOCA and future access to the community fund.
      </small>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :intent_signature, class: "form-control mb-4", id: "intent-signature", required: true %>
            <label for="intent-signature">Type Your Name to Represent Your Signature</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :intent_signature_date, class: "form-control datepicker", id: "intent_signature_date" %>
            <label for="intent_signature_date">Date</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->
      </div> <!-- row -->

      <h5 class="mb-0 toca-uppercase">Release Agreement</h5>
      <small>
        I agree to the release of confidential information from TOCA Cares to the Associate Emergency Fund Committee and to allow verification by Helping Hands Ministries, Inc., of information pertinent to this request, including a credit bureau report, prior to receipt of any funds.
      </small>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :release_signature, class: "form-control mb-4", id: "release-signature", required: true %>
            <label for="release-signature">Type Your Name to Represent Your Signature</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
          <div class="md-form">
            <%= f.text_field :release_signature_date, class: "form-control datepicker", id: "release_signature_date" %>
            <label for="release_signature_date">Date</label>
          </div> <!-- md-form -->
        </div> <!-- col -->
      </div> <!-- row -->

    </section> <!-- signatures -->



  </div> <!-- form fields -->



  <div class="form-actions text-center pb-5 info-section">
    <%= button_tag "Save for Later", type: 'submit', name: "application_status_id", value: 2, class: "btn btn-light" %>
    <%= button_tag "Submit for Consideration", type: 'submit', name: "application_status_id", value: 3, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>











<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.datepicker').pickadate();

    $('.info-section').hide();
    $('.hardship-only').hide();
    <% if @app_form.application_type == "Hardship" %>
      $('.info-section').show();
      $('.hardship-only').show();
    <% elsif @app_form.application_type == "Scholarship" %>
      $('.info-section').show();
      $('.non-hardship').show();
    <% elsif @app_form.application_type == "Charity" %>
      $('.info-section').show();
      $('.non-hardship').show();
    <% end %>

    var clearHardshipFields = function() {
      $("#for-other-email").val("");
      $("#recipient-toca-email").val("");
      $('#for_other').prop('checked', false);
      $(".for-other-content").hide();
      $("#bank_name").val("");
      $("#bank_phone").val("");
      $("#bank_address").val("");
      $("#accident").prop('checked', false);
      $("#catastrophe").prop('checked', false);
      $("#counseling").prop('checked', false);
      $("#family_emergency").prop('checked', false);
      $("#health").prop('checked', false);
      $("#memorial").prop('checked', false);
      $("#other_hardship").prop('checked', false);
      $("#app_form_other_hardship_description").val("");
    };

    var clearNonHardshipFields = function() {
      $("#institution_contact").val("");
      $("#institution_name").val("");
      $("#institution_phone").val("");
      $("#institution_address").val("");
    };

    $('#hardship').click(function() {
       $('.application-type-box').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
       $('#app_form_application_type').val('Hardship');
       $('.charity-field').addClass('hidden');
       $('.scholarship-field').addClass('hidden');
       $('.hardship-field').removeClass('hidden');
       $('.info-section').show();
       $('.hardship-only').show();
       $('.non-hardship').hide();
       clearNonHardshipFields();
    });
    $('#scholarship').click(function() {
      $('.application-type-box').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $('#app_form_application_type').val('Scholarship');
      $('.hardship-field').addClass('hidden');
      $('.charity-field').addClass('hidden');
      $('.scholarship-field').removeClass('hidden');
      $('.non-hardship').show();
      $('.hardship-only').hide();
      clearHardshipFields();
      $('.info-section').show();
    });
    $('#charity').click(function() {
       $('.application-type-box').removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
       $('#app_form_application_type').val('Charity');
       $('.hardship-field').addClass('hidden');
       $('.charity-field').removeClass('hidden');
       $('.scholarship-field').addClass('hidden');
       $('.non-hardship').show();
       $('.hardship-only').hide();
       clearHardshipFields();
       $('.info-section').show();
    });

    $(".for-other-content").hide();
    var forOtherStuff = function() {
      if( $("#for_other").is(':checked')) {
          $(".for-other-content").show();
      } else {
          $(".for-other-content").hide();
          $("#for-other-email").val("");
          $("#recipient-toca-email").val("");
      }
    };
    forOtherStuff();
    $(".for_other").click(function() { forOtherStuff(); });

    $(".loan-stuff").hide();
    var loanStuff = function() {
      if( $("#loan_preferred").is(':checked')) {
          $(".loan-stuff").show();
      } else {
          $(".loan-stuff").hide();
          $("#app_form_loan_preferred_description").val("");
      }
    };
    loanStuff();
    $("#loan_preferred").click(function() { loanStuff(); });



   });
</script>
```

Can anyone see why this has stopped working?

Comment: There's no jquery hooked to your application_status_id button tags.  If you want to submit the form with the button you'd need to attach it via:  f.submit_tag so rails is aware it's a part of the form.  Else, write an "on click" jquery function to handle appropriately.

Comment: @bkunzi01 you don't need javascript to submit forms using buttons with type=submit, `f.submit_tag` creates an input tag with type submit, but forms can also be submitted with buttons with type=submit (which provides more customization than input type=submit tags)

Comment: @Liz, do you see anything on the browser's dev tools network tab? you said it worked before, what changed on the code?

Comment: @bkunzi01 Using `f.submit` and `submit_tag` both remove the name from the button, showing only the numerical value.  They both exhibit the same behavior (nothing happening) as well.

Comment: @arieljuod Only stylistic changes were made since they functioned, unfortunately.  Nothing that should change the functionality.

Comment: You didn't answer if you see something using the browser's dev tools (an error on the console? do you see a new line on the network tab when you click the buttons?) might it be that you have some javascript that could be interfeering your buttons' click event? the code you show is ok, so the problem must be somewhere else

Comment: @arieljuod Nothing in the network tab, but in the console I get `An invalid form control with name='app_form[for_other_email]' is not focusable.`  Finally a lead!  Googling....

Comment: Personally, I just rewrite the form until I found what introduces the problem (you don't need to rethink it, just comment everything and start uncommenting in chunks). You have to narrow it down to find the problem, the best way to do that if you have no clear indications is to remove everything so you start fresh

Comment: @arieljuod Your dev tools console idea for the win.  It was a field that was both required and hidden preventing the submission.  All fixed!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there was a field that was both required and hidden.  The error was preventing submission, but only showed up when I checked the dev tools console.

It showed up saying `An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable`, which I fixed using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22148080/an-invalid-form-control-with-name-is-not-focusable) and made the specified fields optional.